# How to find network foscam from C#

Tags: c#, udp, ip-camera

I am in the process of creating a very nice C# Winforms application, for controlling and viewing my two foscams.

One of the key things i would like very much to have, is the ability to search the network for cameras!

I know of the "IP Camera Tool" thats very quickly finds the cameras, but i have not been able to recreate it at all (and don't want third-party application).

After searching for days on the internet, i have found "some" documentation, but after many hours of trial and error, i am at a loss here..

The documentation uses UDP packets, you send a command, and the cameras respond back.
First off, i used wireshark to intercept the "IP Camera Tool"s send packet, and replicated it in C#, and the cameras DO respond, but the response does not make any sense, and when i try to intercept it with my application, i only get a small portion of the response, from only the first camera to respond (udp stopped listening)

If there is anyone out there with some knowledge and/or code snippets, i would be very grateful! :)

Documentation:
http://foscam.us/forum/download/file.php?id=522  (pdf)

I had written some code to send the response, but i just had a BSOD and the whole .cs file got screwed..

it was basicly just creating a UdpClient object and send a string that was converted so it mached up with this: 4d:4f:5f:49:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:04:00:00:00:04:00:00:00:00:00:00:01

and broadcast it on port 10000.
And then! udp.recive would start right after send, and intercept (the first part of the message only) :-/

Any pointers to listen for more than just the first part of a response, would be very helpful!

I made some nice screenshots of everything for this post, but as this is my first post here, i can't add the images :-/

Thankyou :)
Please let me know if there is any info i missed :)

Kind regards
Niels

Edit:

Links to images:

Documentation (Search_Req):

http://**dl.nxsoft.dk/stackpics/doc_search_req.PNG**

Documentation (Search_Response):

http://dl.nxsoft.dk/stackpics/doc_search_resp.PNG

Wireshark Output (IP Camera Tool):

http://dl.nxsoft.dk/stackpics/fs_ws_ipTool.PNG

Wireshark Output (Camera Response):

http://dl.nxsoft.dk/stackpics/fs_ws_cam.PNG

Comment: add the urls to your post and i'll swap them for images if you like?

Comment: Hi Chris, I made them with the windows snipping tool and just pasted them in, so i don't have the urls im afraid :-/

Comment: Remade the screen shots, and uploaded to my website and linked in post :-)